# Cannot receive PubSub push message in appengine flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, app-engine-flexible

I created a POST endpoint in the appengine flexible environment (Java/Spring Boot). It is in the same Google project as the PubSub subscriptions.
I checked and this POST endpoint is accessible from outside world. I can post data to this endpoint using Postman from my local PC.
But my controller does not get the requests from the push subscription.

I tried the simple endpoint urls like /push and also the recommended urls like /_ah/push-handlers/push but the results are the same.

I can see in the Stackdriver logs a lot of messages:

```
{
 metadata: {
      projectId: "myproject"   
      serviceName: "appengine.googleapis.com"   
      zone: "us-central1-b"   
      labels: {…}   
      timestamp: "2016-12-06T19:17:51.922Z"   
 }
     insertId: "1u1o1hqf77guah"  
     log: "appengine.googleapis.com/nginx.request"  
     structPayload: {
          method: "POST"   
          latencySeconds: "0.000"   
          referer: "-"   
          host: "-"   
          user: "-"   
          code: "307"   
          remote: "130.211.3.227"   
          agent: "-"   
          path: "/push"   
          size: "180"
     } 
}
```

But my push controller is never called.

When I post to this URL from Postman, I get similar 307 redirect (the only difference in the agent) and then after my controller responds I can see the 200 response:

```
{
     metadata: {
          projectId: "myproject"   
          serviceName: "appengine.googleapis.com"   
          zone: "us-central1-b"   
          labels: {…}   
          timestamp: "2016-12-06T19:10:14.226Z"   
     }
         insertId: "1acos4zf74fb5r"  
         log: "appengine.googleapis.com/nginx.request"  
         structPayload: {
          method: "POST"   
          latencySeconds: "0.035"   
          referer: "-"   
          host: "-"   
          user: "-"   
          code: "200"   
          remote: "130.211.0.196"   
          agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"   
          path: "/push"   
          size: "727"   
     }
 }
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
# [START appyaml]
runtime: java
env: flex

runtime_config:
   jdk: openjdk8

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: optional

# [END appyaml]
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I also had faced same problem.
I had a scala akka-http app on GAE flex. 
I think that this is a bug of flex because I got success when I edited the push-endpoint on GAE Standard(golang).

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug but...

> As of today the issue has been resolved. Thank you for your patience.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/cloud-pubsub/issues/detail?id=49#makechanges